# 64 bit .Net Class Library issue

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, dllimport, class-library, vs-web-site-project

I've built my .Net Class Library with  **Platform Target : 64 bit** on a **64 bit operating system**. But when i've added it as a reference in my website i am unable to access its classes.

I've figure out that if i build my Class Library with Platform Target: 32 bit or Any CPU its working fine. But i want to do it with Platform Target: 64 bit.

Please let me know if i am missing something and make me correct.

Operating system : Windows 8.1 64 bit
IDE :    Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Thanks

Comment: Is your asp.net server running as a 64 bit process?

Comment: Why do you want to target a specific arquitecture? "Any CPU" should be enough for most of the cases since it automatically convert to correct machine code. Do you have any x64 specific logic?

Comment: I have no idea how to check it . Can you please tell me?

Comment: Yes you got nice point Claudio but actually my senior assigned this task to me so i've to make it work with 64 bit option and i'm also very curious about it why it's not working. In the end if its didn't work i will follow "Any CPU" option which you suggest.

Comment: Do you have any idea if i am missing any configuration settings in Class Library or website?

Comment: I suspect your web site is running in 32-bit mode.  If it is, it won't be able to load 64-bit assemblies.  If you have to run in 64-bit mode then your solution is to set the web-site to run in 64-bit via IIS (assuming it's running on a 64-bit server).

Comment: Yes b.pell i've enable the option of "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Expression for websites and web project" under project properties  but  it didn't fix the problem.